# Factor $2^{15}-1=32767$ into a product of two smaller positive integers. Is there a method?

Tags: factoring

I can't think of anything short of dividing it until I find a factor. What could be a practical way of doing it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

HINT: $p^{rs}-1=(p^r-1)(p^{r(s-1)}+p^{r(s-2)}+ \dots + 1)$

Comment: Its better to explicitly mention : $p$ is an integer and  $r,s$ are positive integers

Comment: @labbhattacharjee For this purpose, yes. But $p$ need not be an integer - I might just as well have used an indeterminate $x$, and neither need $r$ be an integer. If $x=p^r$ and $s$ is a positive integer then $x^s-1=(x-1)(x^{s-1}+x^{s-2}+\dots +1)$.